# Calculating conditional probabilities given a bivariate gaussian

Tags: bayesian, self-study, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50675/calculating-the-optimal-decision-boundary).

---

I have two classes, $C_1$ and $C_2$.

$C_1$ is a bivariate Gaussian with mean $\mu = (0,0)$ and covariance $\Sigma = I$

$C_2$ is a bivariate Gaussian with mean $\mu = (1,3)$ and covariance $\Sigma = 2I$,
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I am trying to calculate $P(x|C_1)$ and $P(x|C_2)$ so I can eventually calculate $P(C|x)$

To calculate $P(x|C_1)$ and $P(x|C_2)$ this I'm using the formula for a bivariate normal distribution found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html).

My covariance is zero, which makes this a little bit easier.

**When I use this calculate $P(x|C_1)$ I have...**

$z=x_1^2 - x_2^2$

$p=0$

$p(x_1,x_2) = (\frac{1}{2\pi})e^{-z/2}$

**When I use this to calculate $P(x|C_2)$ I have...**

$z=\frac{1}{4}( (x_1-1)^2 + (x_2-3)^2 )$

$p=0$

$p(x_1,x_2) = (\frac{1}{8\pi})e^{z/8}$

Did I do this correctly? Also, I'm a bit confused as to whether what I'm doing even gives me $P(x|C_1)$ and $P(x|C_2)$. I'm a bit over my head in the class I'm in, so if I'm totally wrong there please correct me.

Anyways, with these two values I'm supposed to calculate $P(C|x)$ using Bayes rule (I think). I have the priors of $C_1$ and $C_2$ (they are 0.4 and 0.6 respectively), but I'm lost exactly on how to calculate $P(C|x)$ with this.

**Could somebody basically just check over some of my work and help me out with the process using Bayes rule to calculate $P(C|x)$?**

EDIT: My end goal here is to calculate an optimal decision boundary between $C_1$ and $C_2$, if I'm going the complete wrong way here let me know, but from what I've gathered through time spent on this site, I think I'm headed the right way.

Comment: If this is work for a class (yes even if it's not explicitly work to hand in), please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's been added

Comment: When you say "$C_1$ is two Gaussian variables" do you mean a mixture?

Comment: I made some edits to your question; please double check I didn't screw up the mathematics on you.

Comment: Your edits look okay to me. And when I say that I mean that in the problem given to me it says C1 is a class of two gaussian variables. I would assume that means a mixture of the two

Comment: Please what is $x$ ?

Comment: @Hoser, no it is not a mixture, assuming this is the same question referred to in your other post. Each class is a **2-dimensional Gaussian distribution** with means at (0,0) and (1,3).

Comment: The edits, while essentially innocuous, potentially change the meaning of the question in a substantial way. Reinterpreting "two gaussians..." as "bivariate gaussian..." may actually end up obscuring the source of the OP's confusion and a common misconception!

Comment: @cardinal, The OP is the one who reinterpreted the bivariate gaussian to be two separate gaussians. From his previous post: `Suppose points in R2 are being obtained from two classes, C1 and C2, both of which are well described by bivariate Gaussians with means at (0,0) and (1,3) and covariances I and 2I respectively.` I was trying to point out the confusion and clarify it in the post.

Comment: @hoser, This [lecture note](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281A-fall04/lectures/lec-9-30.pdf) explains how to derive the boundary you're after. I'd suggest looking it over.

Comment: Dear @jerad, ok. That was a little out of context, I guess, since I was judging only by the edit history of this question, which does not link, or make reference to, the OP's other questions. Perhaps adding appropriate links would help since others might have the same reaction. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Hoser has now posed three questions: this one, the [one cited in this
question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50675/6633), and the [one where he was told the decision boundary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50592/6633) for his
problem on the same topic,
and his confusion seems to increase every time.

For *this problem*,

- **There is no need to *calculate* $P(x\mid C_1)$ and $P(x\mid C_2)$.**
  You are *told* that your observation which you denote as $x$ is a **pair**
  of real numbers that are to be treated as random variables
  $(X,Y)$ whose *conditional joint density* (this is what is meant
  by your $P(x\mid C_i)$ is **given** to be

  - jointly normal (a.k.a bivariate normal) with mean vector $[0,0]$
    and covariance matrix $I$ for the case $i=1$.
  - jointly normal (a.k.a bivariate normal) with mean vector $[1,3]$
    and covariance matrix $2I$ for the case $i=2$.

  In *both* cases, $X$ and $Y$ are (*conditionally*) independent
  random variables.  So, $P(x\mid C_1)$ is the **bivariate** density
  function $f_{X,Y\mid C_1}(u,v \mid C_1)$ and so should have things
  like $\frac{1}{2\pi}, $exponential functions, $u^2/2$ and $v^2/2$
  in it, and no product terms $uv$ anywhere. Can you **write** down
  this function of $(u,v)$? How about $P(x\mid C_2)$ which will
  have $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, exponential functions, $(u-1)^2/8$ and $(v-3)^2/8$
  in it, and no product terms $uv$ anywhere?

  **The work you have shown in your question is incorrect, by the way.**
- The $C$ in your $P(C)$ has **nothing to do** with $C_1$ and $C_2$.
  It is the probability of a **correct** decision, and to find this
  probability, you first need to determine the *decision boundary*
  which *partitions* the plane into two _regions which can be called
  $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$, and then do **two** separate
  calculations as described below for the cases $i=1$ and $i=2$:

  - what is the probability of a correct decision when the observation $x$
    (which is a pair of real numbers) belongs to class $C_i$?  To do this,
    you work with $f_{X,Y\mid C_i}(u,v \mid C_i)$ and calculate
    $$P\{(X,Y) \in \Gamma_1 \mid C_i\} = \int\int_{(u,v) \in \Gamma_i}
    f_{X,Y\mid C_i}(u,v \mid C_i)\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv.$$
    If you are lucky, the decision boundary will be a straight line
    and this integral can be evaluated easily by a change of variables
    involving a rotation of coordinates about the mean point $(0,0)$
    or $(1,3)$ as the case may be; otherwise, numerical integration
    will be required.  Call the probability thus obtained $P(C\mid C_i)$.

  Next, you will need to combine your answer using the *law of total
  probability* to get
  $$P(C) = P(C\mid C_1)P(C_1) + P(C\mid C_2)P(C_2)
  = P(C\mid C_1)\times 0.4 + P(C\mid C_2)\times 0.6$$

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate this. I apologize if I went about all of this the wrong way.

Comment: Quick question, for $P(X|C_2)$ would it not be $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ rather than $\frac{1}{2\pi}$? This is due to the covariance matrix being $2I$ rather than $I$ I believe.

Comment: If you don't mind, [this](http://i.imgur.com/fFp27wE.png?1) is what my eventual boundary looks like when plotted in R. Does this look correct given a quick glance?